# How can I have my trailing widget alight to the right?

Tags: flutter

I have a `ListView` and I want to have a switch on the right side of every `ListTile`. But the switch appears to be aligned to the left. How can I make it align to the right?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column
        (
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: 
          [ 
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Stack
              (
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: NavigatePopButton(),
                  ),
                  Align
                  (
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Text
                    (
                      'Settings',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ),
            Expanded
            (
              flex: 4,
              child: MediaQuery.removePadding
              (
                context: context,
                removeTop: true,
                child: ListView.separated
                (
                  itemCount: 3,
                  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(height: 1.0), 
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)
                  {
                      return ListTile
                      (
                        title: Text(settings()[index].value),
                        trailing: settings()[index].controller,
                      );
                  }       
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: This is what I have]

[image: This is what I want]

Answer (score 0):

`ListTile` has a `Padding` of it's own. Try tweaking that value,

For example

```
return ListTile
(
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0.0),
  title: Text(arguments.groups[index]),
  onTap: () => onGroupTap(arguments.groups[index]),
  trailing: Switch(
    value: true,
    onChanged: (isSwitched) => print('is switched'),
  ),
);
```

Comment: It does not appear to have any effect on the switch. It does however on the text. If I set the right padding to 0.0 the text on the left aligns perfectly to the left. So I tried multiple paddings and even set them all to 0.0 but nothing seems to be affecting the switch.

Comment: Have you tried the widget `SwitchListTile` instead of `ListTile`?

Comment: Maybe you are adding some right space in a parent Widget of the listTile. Check this [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/79f825d73a6eda80cf9af431387027e6)

Comment: I did try the SwitchListTile but it doesn't have the OnTap which I do need

Comment: Have you seen the Dartpad I told you?

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate the issue you are facing. I see `Switch` aligned to the right properly. Sample working code below:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.separated
          (
          itemCount: 5,
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(height: 0.0),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            return ListTile
              (
              title: Text('Test'),
              onTap: () {},
              trailing: Switch(
                value: true,
                onChanged: (isSwitched) => print('is switched'),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the code around it? I added the entire build method to my post.